# Click button to get the sum of the first 12 Fibonacci numbers

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I want to get and add the first 12 even fibonacci numbers and have it appear on my page when I click the button. Right now my code gets and adds the even numbers. How do I limit it to the first 12 even numbers?

Thank you in advance.  http://jsfiddle.net/lakenney/oryygn4y/

```
    // first we get the HTML for the button
var getFibSum = document.getElementById("sumFib");

//then we set the event handler for when the button is clicked
getFibSum.onclick = function(){
               document.getElementById("sumFibResult").innerHTML = twelveEvenFibonacciSum();
 }

 /*
  *  twelveEvenFibonacciSum - calulates the sum of the first 12 even fibonacci numbers, with 0, 1 being the first two numbers of the sequence
  */

    function twelveEvenFibonacciSum(){
     /// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
        // Loop that generates Fibonacci numbers. 
        console.clear();

        var fib = [0, 1]; //Initialize array
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i= 2; i <= 50; i++) {
            fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];    
            var integer = fib[i];
            if(integer  % 2 == 0) {
                 // console.log("my current even fib is " + fib[i]);
                 var sumFibResult = sum += fib[i];
                console.log("my current even fib added to sum " + sumFibResult);
            }
            // Loop until we have 12 even numbers

            }

        //console.log(fib);
       return sumFibResult;
 }
```

Comment: `sumFibResult` needs to be declared at the top of your function, not inside the inner loop.

Comment: Either that or just return `sum`.

Comment: Putting var sumFibResult didn't change anything. It's the sumFebResult that needs to get returned to the html. But thank you anyway Austin.

Comment: I've updated my code. I want to get and add the first 12 even numbers. I'm getting the even numbers and i'm adding them. How do I cut it off after adding the first 12 even numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to the outer scope which gets incremented each time your function is called. Return when this equals 12.

```
    for (var i= 2; i <= 50; i++) {
        fib[i] = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];    
        var integer = fib[i];
        if(integer  % 2 == 0) {
             // console.log("my current even fib is " + fib[i]);
             var sumFibResult = sum += fib[i];
            console.log("my current even fib added to sum " + sumFibResult);
            timesIncremented++;
        }
        // Loop until we have 12 even numbers
        if(timesIncremented >= 12) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with. I've been trying to do that and I keep getting myself into infinite loops and crashing my computer. I'm a newbie.

Comment: @user3120646 Edited to give you an example. I didn't test your code, but this is the general idea.

Comment: YES! I knew it was a simple solution. I kept trying to incorporate a do while, etc. I just kept putting the return in the wrong place! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, I am happy with it. How do I accept it? I clicked the check mark and turned it green; does that mean accept? I'm new here too. :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's how you accept it. That accepted it. Thanks!